# Android Studio - Path to sound with variable

Tags: android, audio

I wanna to after pressing button my application played randomly track from list.But I have a problem in this line `mySounds = MediaPlayer.create (this, R.raw.myItems[n]);`
If I do not enter "R.raw.FILENAME" I get the following error: "Cannot find symbol variable myItems". Here is my full code.

```
MediaPlayer mySounds;
public void Play_sound(View v) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int n=rand.nextInt(2);
    String[]myItems={"itemA","itemB"};
    mySounds = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.myItems[n]);
    mySounds.start();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try getting the resource identifier first and then passing this in when creating your media player, like so:

```
MediaPlayer mySounds;
public void Play_sound(View v) {
Random rand = new Random();
int n=rand.nextInt(2);
String[]myItems={"itemA","itemB"};
//this line added to get the id of the random item
int randomSoundId = getResources().getIdentifier(myItems[n], "raw", getPackageName());
//then give this id to the MediaPlayer
mySounds = MediaPlayer.create(this, randomSoundId);
mySounds.start();
}
```